# How do I configure the NewWindowRequested in Webview2 Core using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, webview2

I am creating a PowerShell script which loads Speedtest.net but I do not want users to navigate away or click on links to open new web pages. I have found a way to detect when the source changes in the userform to go back to the desired URL but some links on the page open new windows and I am not able to suppress that. Here is the code I have:

`

```
$ScriptPath = [System.AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.TrimEnd('\')
[xml]$XAML = @"
<Window x:Class="WPF_Getting_Started.MainWindow"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfTest"
      xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
      mc:Ignorable="d"
      Title="Internet Speed Test $ScriptVersion"
      Height="450"
      Width="800"
>
    <DockPanel>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView"
                  Source="http://www.speedtest.net"
   >
            <wv2:WebView2.CreationProperties>
                <wv2:CoreWebView2CreationProperties BrowserExecutableFolder="" UserDataFolder="$ENV:TEMP"/>
            </wv2:WebView2.CreationProperties>
        </wv2:WebView2>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
"@
#
# Assembly
#
    [void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
    [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("$ScriptPath\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("$ScriptPath\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll")
    [void][reflection.assembly]::LoadFile("$ScriptPath\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf.dll")
#
# Execution
#
    $XAML.Window.RemoveAttribute("x:Class")
    $XAML.Window.RemoveAttribute("mc:Ignorable")
    $Reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML)
    $Form=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($Reader)
    $XAML.SelectNodes("//*[@*[contains(translate(name(.),'n','N'),'Name')]]")  | ForEach-Object {  
        New-Variable  -Name $_.Name -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name) -Force  
    }
    # Webview
    $webview_SourceChanged={
        $webView.Source = "http://www.speedtest.net"
    }
    $webView.add_SourceChanged($webview_SourceChanged)
    # Other form properties
    $Screens = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::AllScreens
    $Screen = $Screens | Where {$_.Primary -eq "True"}
    $script:Bounds = $Screen.Bounds
    $Form.Left = $Bounds.Left
    $Form.Top = $Bounds.Top
    $Form.Height = $Bounds.Height
    $Form.Width = $Bounds.Width
    [void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

`

I thought maybe I could use Event detection:

add_NewWindowRequested

I tried to create an object:

[Microsoft.Web.Webview2.Core.CoreWebView2] $webviewcore = New-Object 'Microsoft.Web.Webview2.Core.CoreWebView2'

But I get an error " A constructor was not found. Cannot find an appropriate constructor for type Microsoft.Web.Webview2.Core.CoreWebView2."

Can any please help me understand how I could stop the Webview2 control from opening a new window?